# PayPal Sandbox suddenly outputting proxy error for adaptive payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

**Edit: For some reason it's working again. I did not need to log in to developer.paypal.com either. If anyone knows why, that would be useful. Thanks!**

For the past few months I have been developing a site using PayPal's adaptive payments, specifically the chained payments method. I am using the [embedded payment](https://www.x.com/developers/community/blogs/praveen/switching-over-embedded-payments?view=overview) method from a site that uses SSL. The integration had been working perfectly for months until a day or two ago. It was even still working right after I imported my old sandbox accounts to the new developer.paypal.com sandbox.

After submitting the payment from the site's form, the browser spins for a minute or two. The error generated after a few minutes is the following:

> The proxy server could not handle the request GET
>   /webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/corepay Reason: **Error during SSL
>   Handshake with remote server**

```
$API_UserName = "us business account from developer.paypal.com sandbox";
$API_Password = "password from developer.paypal.com sandbox";
$API_Signature = "singature from developer.paypal.com sandbox";
// AppID is preset for sandbox use
//   If your application goes live, you will be assigned a value for the live environment by PayPal as part of the live onboarding process
$API_AppID = "APP-80W284485P519543T";
$API_Endpoint = "";

if ($Env == "sandbox") 
{
    $API_Endpoint = "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments";
}
else
{
    $API_Endpoint = "https://svcs.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments";
}
```

If I am not mistaken, I believe the error is being generated when the redirect happens from this function here:

```
function RedirectToPayPal ( $cmd )
{
    // Redirect to paypal.com here
    global $Env;

    $payPalURL = "";

    if ($Env == "sandbox") 
    {
        $payPalURL = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?expType='.$_POST['expType'].$cmd;
    }
    else
    {
        $payPalURL = "https://www.paypal.com/webscr?" . $cmd;
    }

    header("Location: ".$payPalURL);
    exit;
}
```

Edit: I changed the $payPalURL to "https://developer.paypal.com..." as suggested and got the following:

> Service Temporarily Unavailable
>
> The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to
>   maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to have been an issue with the sandbox.paypal.com server that disabled adaptive payments for a couple days. Everything seems to be functioning as it had been previously. Thank you to Dennis for his input.

**Edit:**
This appears to be ongoing and intermittent

Answer (score 0):

After the recent code change this flow now requires you to log in to https://developer.paypal.com first. I am checking to see if this was intentional or is a code bug.

Comment: You may be on the right track with that one. Now I get this: Service Temporarily Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I was saying. You need to to log in to https://developer.paypal.com first. That sets a cookie in your browser, after that you can go to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?expType='.$_POST['expType'].$cmd

Comment: It is resolved. I do not need to be logged into developer.paypal.com either. It must have been a temporary sandbox issue.