# Paypal Adaptive Payments 500 proxy error

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm seeing the following error message when attempting to perform a simple payment using the PayPal Adaptive Payments API and the Explicit Approval Payment Flow in the sandbox environment:

```
Proxy Error

The proxy server could not handle the request GET /webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/expresscheckoutincontextremembermeflow.
Reason: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server
```

As per [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644100/paypal-sandbox-suddenly-outputting-proxy-error-for-adaptive-payments), this issue has supposedly been resolved, but I'm still unable to perform a simple payment in the sandbox environment.

The API call to generate a payKey is returning successfully:

```
{
'responseEnvelope': {
'ack': 'Success', 
'timestamp': '2013-04-01T10:00:33.572-07:00', 
'build': '5563463', 
'correlationId': '9ddb6d34b8b31'
}, 
'paymentExecStatus': 'CREATED', 
'payKey': 'AP-30241506EH984280M'
}
```

and the following series of redirects are occurring:

https:// www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?expType=light&paykey=AP-30241506EH984280M

redirects to:
https:// www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/payinit?iframecookie=1364835660832&paykey=AP-30241506EH984280M&expType=light

which redirects to:
https:// www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/corepay

which redirects to:
https:// www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/expresscheckoutincontextremembermeflow

which gives the 500 proxy error after approximately 210 seconds.

Additionally, if I attempt the workaround of logging into developer.paypal.com in another tab first, I get a 404 error on the initial request:
https:// www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?expType=light&paykey=AP-45P14958V28124917

I've searched and searched and poked and prodded this issue to death...anyone else seeing this problem, and does anyone have a working resolution?

Comment: I'm getting pretty much the same issues as you are. I have an embedded adaptive payments system (chained payments) and I wasn't getting any response at all (or maybe I was, after waiting a few minutes, even so it would have been an error). I read somewhere that the Sandbox has been changed so that you have to log in first, so I did that in another tab and I keep getting a 502 proxy error. I guess their servers are having issues? The rest of the PayPal site/Sandbox site seem to be really slow for me right now, they could just be experiencing problems.

Comment: I'm also getting the exact same error when I just go to
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/ on my web browser!

Answer (score 0):

We are rolling a patch later tonight which we expect to fix this issue permanently.

Comment: Is the patch rolled out now?

Comment: Unfortunately, the team ran into some release issues and the patch did not get applied yet however we took a few steps to mitigate the code bug. Can you confirm that you are still unable to test?

Comment: Even when the problem occurred it wasn't reproducible every time. Now it seems to be working every time, but I wanted to be sure it is fixed.

Comment: The patch was released yesterday so hopefully this issue is resolved permanently.